# Jquery Clone Dropdownlist and Textbox, Rename Increment By 1

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery and need some help here.  I am trying to copy/clone a SELECT box and TEXT box with exact same option items, but rename them to the new name by incrementing 1.

Example, I have this SELECT dropdown.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="ddl_1" id="ddl_1" name="ddl_1">
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txt_1" name="txt_1">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- The Clone SELECT and TEXT Boxes will append below here. -->

</table>
```

When the "Add" button clicked, it will clone both ddl_1 and txt_1 to the new row, and rename those to ddl_2 and txt_2. like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="ddl_1" id="ddl_1">
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txt_1" name="txt_1">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="ddl_2" id="ddl_2">
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txt_2" name="txt_2">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- The Clone SELECT and TEXT Boxes will append below here. -->

</table>
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Instead of cloning the existing row `<td>`, you should use JavaScript to generate the `<td>` row. Then when someone clicks "add" you can call your row generation method again.

Comment: I'm writing a fiddle for you. One moment, almost done.

Comment: Here's a quick and dirty example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Y8YZ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var counter = 1;

$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
    counter++;
    $('table').find("tr:eq(1)").clone().appendTo("table").find('select')
               .attr({
                   'name': 'ddl_' + counter,
                   'id'   : 'ddl_' + counter
               })
               .closest('td').next('td').find('input')
               .attr({
                   'name': 'ddl_' + counter,
                   'id'   : 'ddl_' + counter
               })
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UkzU3/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cloning the existing row `<td>`, you should use JavaScript to generate the `<td>` row. Then when someone clicks "add" you can call your row generation method again.

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3Y8YZ/2/)

```
var $table = $('table');
var rowCount = 0;

var generateRow = function(indx){
    
    $table.append('<tr><td>This row ID: '+indx+'</td>\
        <td>\
            <select name="ddl_'+indx+'" id="ddl_'+indx+'">\
                <option value="1">One</option>\
                <option value="2">Two</option>\
                <option value="3">Three</option>\
            </select>\
        </td>\
        <td>\
            <input type="text" id="txt_'+indx+'" name="txt_'+indx+'">\
        </td></tr>');
    
}

var addRow = function(){
    generateRow(++rowCount);
}

addRow(); // add first row automatically

$('#btnAdd').click(addRow); // add more rows every time button is clicked
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this. Set a `default` `clone` object, and just proceed from there with some simple `jQuery`.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/4SCp8/

**HTML:**

```
<tr id="template">
    <td>
        <select name="ddl_" id="ddl_" name="ddl_">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txt_" name="txt_" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    $('#btnAdd').on('click', function() {
        counter++;
        $('#template').clone().appendTo($('#table'));
        $('#ddl_').attr('id', 'ddl_'+counter);
        $('#txt_').attr('id', 'txt_'+counter);
    });
});
```